# Semiprime numbers of the form $246810121416\cdots n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Concatenating the first even numbers $246810121416\cdots n$, we might get a semiprime, but the only semiprime I know of such form is $2468101214$. I observe that numbers of the form $246810121416\cdots n$ is (very) hard to be a semiprime number, because they are very often divisible by small odd primes. And I've checked $n\leq1502$ without finding anymore semiprime of such form $(!)$. Are there any more semiprimes of such form?

Comment: What is the motivation behind this question ?

Comment: Finding semiprimes of the form  2468101214....?

Comment: Yes, I understand this is OEIS A019520 [https://oeis.org/A019520]

Comment: @Shailesh Does every single question really require motivation? To me this seems like recreational mathematics, which can just be done for the sake of doing it. Calculating $\pi$ to billions and billions of digits isn't really useful and yet it's still a nice thing to do.

Comment: @Robin 8 years later, but point taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concatenation of the first $1789$ positive even integers is probably semiprime.

Comment: Are you very positive about that ? : D

Comment: I checked half the number with mpz_probab_prime_p and reps=50.

Comment: That's 24681012....357435763578 ? How many digits it has ? : D

Comment: It has exactly 6600 digits.

Comment: So we have N = 14 , 3578 , .....

Comment: Actually, according to Maple, it has 6604 digits.

Comment: What the...., thanks Robert! : )

Comment: To 10,000 terms, 7 and 1789 are the only semiprimes (using BPSW).

Answer (score 7):

If $s_n$ is the concatenation of $2,4, \ldots, 2n$, then you want $s_n/2$ to be prime.  $s_n/2$ has on the order of $n \log n$ digits, so heuristically its probability of being prime is on the order of $1/(n \log n)$.  Now
$\sum_n 1/(n \log n)$ diverges, but extremely slowly: the partial sums grow like $\log \log n$.  Therefore we might expect to look at something like
$\exp(\exp(m))$ terms to get $m$ of your semiprimes.

Comment: @starwars8comingsoon And this answer says you should expect to concatenate roughly 1600 even numbers before you find another. So... a pretty big number.

Comment: @pjs36, I've checked the first 751 even numbers, and that's 2468101214....149815001502.